# Java date parsing has stranger behavior where parsing different date in different timezone

Tags: java, date, parsing, timezone, simpledateformat

Here I am trying to parse two dates in java. Date 1 is "2021-01-01" and date 2 is "2021-04-01". But after parsing Java generating Date object with a different timezone. Really confused by this behavior. I am looking at the same timezone and that is EDT.

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
    import java.text.ParseException;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.Locale;
    
    
    public class DateCalculation {
    
        private static final DateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
    
        public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {
            Date date1 = getDateFromString("2021-01-01");
            System.out.println("Date 1: " + date1);
    
            Date date2 = getDateFromString("2021-04-01");
            System.out.println("Date 2: " + date2);
        }
    
        public static Date getDateFromString(String dateString) throws ParseException {
            if(dateString == null || dateString.trim().length() == 0)
                return null;
    
            dateString = dateString.replace("\"", ""); // Remove quotes
            return formater.parse(dateString);
        }
    }


Output:
Date 1: Fri Jan 01 00:00:00 EST 2021
Date 2: Thu Apr 01 00:00:00 EDT 2021
```

Comment: There is no EDT in January.

Comment: Also, remember, `Date#toString` is using an internal formatter, oh, and you should be using the `java.time` API over the older `java.util` based date classes

Comment: Can you share with me the code snippet, please?

Comment: “EDT” is not a [real time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Comment: I think I understand your confusion. And I don’t think it’s documented behaviour, but this is as confusing the old `Date` class was behaving (and `SimpleDateFormat` was even worse). I say ‘was’ because the good solution, really the only sensible solution is to stop using those classes and switch to [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html). `Date` and related classes are long outdated.

Comment: EST and EDT are not different time zones. Many time zones are referred to by different abbreviations depending on whether summer time (daylight saving time) is in effect or not. Your abbreviations are probably for Eastern Standard Time (meaning no summer time) and Eastern Daylight Time (meaning summer time). Both are used for Eastern Time in both Australia and North America, in your case probably the latter.

Comment: @shmosel Strictly speaking in Australia they have Eastern Daylight Time in January. I still believe that your comment hits the OP’s problem spot-on.

Answer (score 2):

You are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

## `LocalDate`

For a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone, use `LocalDate` class.

```
LocalDate.parse( "2021-04-01" )
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

If you want to represent the first moment of the day for that date in a particular time zone, apply `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

Do not assume the day starts at 00:00:00 . Some dates in some zones start at another time such as 01:00:00 . So let *java.time* determine the first moment.

`EDT` is not a real time zone. Perhaps you meant `America/Montreal`, `America/New_York`, `America/Indiana/Marengo`, or some such.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2022-01-23" ) ;
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Indiana/Marengo" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ld.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```